# What does PATH need to point to for pysolar on Win7. i.e. to use "from pysolar.solar ..."

Tags: python-3.x, path, windows-7

I have found several examples on the web of using pysolar to calculate the suns altitude and other discussions of setting up the Win7 PATH however nothing has explained what PATH should be actually directed at. i.e. a particular pysolar directory or file.  My aim is to add the suns altitude data (get_altitude) to a gnuplot graph of bat house activity captured as temperatures and echo detection, and if linked to sunrise and sunset times.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to import libraries, you the module file should exist in the PYTHONPATH environment variable. To check what exists in that variable right now, you can try

When you install a library, e.g.

```
sudo pip3 install pysolar
```

The path should automatically be pointing to the files (to get really technical, it will exist in the C:\\Lib\site-package folder), and you can start importing it immediately.